# Changing the cursor in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'd like the cursor to be a crosshair when it is over the chart area of a highcharts graph, to indicate to users that they can zoom in. However, I don't want the cursor to be a crosshair when it's over other areas such as the legend or axes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use built-in method `chart.isInsidePlot(plotX, plotY)`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2eje4xxb/1/

Code example:

```
container.on("mousemove", function (event) {
    var chart = container.highcharts();
    if (chart.isInsidePlot(event.pageX - chart.plotLeft, event.pageY - chart.plotTop)) {
        $("body").css({
            cursor: "crosshair"
        });
    } else {
        $("body").css({
            cursor: "default"
        });
    }
});
```

Another idea is to utilize `chart.plotBackgroundColor` option, which creates rect, which can obtain CSS styles:

```
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        plotBackgroundColor: "rgba(10,0,0,0)", // dummy color, to create an element
        events: {
            load: function(){
                if(this.plotBackground) {
                    this.plotBackground.toFront().css({ // move on top to get all events
                        cursor: "crosshair"  
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2eje4xxb/2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can write code to set the cursor style in the mouse events. 
Please find the jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/3Lu7bzmn/5/

**CSS**

```
.cursorCrossHair{
    cursor : crosshair
}
.cursorDefault{
    cursor : default
}
```

**JS** - Shown only specific piece of code which is required to change the cursor. The id of the div used to render the highcharts is called "container". Please refer the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lu7bzmn/5/) to see the full working example.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
         plotOptions: {
             series: {
                 point: {
                     events: {
                         mouseOver: function () {
                             $("#container").removeClass("cursorDefault").addClass("cursorCrossHair");
                         },
                         mouseOut: function () {
                             $("#container").removeClass("cursorCrossHair").addClass("cursorDefault");
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         },

     });
 });
```